# How to put a content between two text in a file into an array or a string

Tags: php

For example, this is top-most part of "how-to.html"

```
 1  <!-- Table of Content -->
 2      <ol>
 3          <li>Intro</li>
 4          <li>Conclusion</li>
 5      </ol>
 6  <!-- / Table of Content -->
 7
 8  <article>
 9      <h2>Introduction</h2>
10
```

**The content between "!-- Table of Content --" is not fixed and may extend or shrink.**

How to only put the contents **between the HTML comments** into an array or a string?
I tried to search on the method however I was unable to find anything like this. The things I found are about changing contents between lines. Since "how-to.html" will grow overtime, I need to only read the content **from  specified texts, not lines**.

You can provide a modified example of the "how-to.html" to reflect your answer.

Comment: Why do I think this reads like school homework?

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker however that does not answer my question. The content between the HTML comments is flexible and may extend or shrink between different "how-to.html" files. I only need to read the content between the HTML comment and not between lines.

Comment: @MarkBaker err I am having problem of reviving my brain to comprehend the php functions in order to solve my problem. It has been quite a while since I last made a script from php ._.

Comment: I'd look at using something like array_filter() with a callback that uses strpos to check for `<!-- ` in the array loaded via file()

Comment: I will see what I can do with your mentioned information. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I'd use a regex, or an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file into an array using `file()`.

```
$file = file('filename.html');
```

Then you can use `array_splice()` to insert into a portion of it.

```
$newlines = array(
   '<ol>',
   '</ol>'
);
$file = array_splice($file, $line_num_to_insert_at, 0, $newlines);
```

You will still need a way to find the line numbers, I'll leave that up to you to do some research.

[array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) can insert into an array at a certain position and also replace existing content in the array.  Look at the manual for more info on how to use it.  The function I provided only inserts, it doesn't replace.

Comment: Thank you. However, this do not answer my question. I am aware of between-lines replacement but I am requesting on the method on replacing content between two different **texts**.

Comment: You should modify your question then: `I am wondering on how to read the content between two lines in a file and then store it into an array or a string.`

Comment: OMG sorry sorry sorry I am so sorry. I didn't notice that my title is horribly wrong! The title has now changed

Comment: I have updated my answer to correspond with inserting contents instead of extracting contents.  You'll still need to research on getting the line numbers.